# Intermittent error with CompareValidator - ValueToCompare property is ""

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have a page with a CompareValidator on it:

```
<asp:textbox id="txtResponseDate" runat="server" />
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="rfvResponseDate" runat="server"
                        controltovalidate="txtResponseDate"
                        display="Dynamic"
                        errormessage="Date is required."
                        setfocusonerror="true">
                    </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
<asp:comparevalidator id="cmvDate" runat="server"
                        controltovalidate="txtResponseDate"
                        display="Dynamic"
                        errormessage="Date must not be before today."
                        operator="GreaterThanEqual"
                        setfocusonerror="true"
                        type="Date">
                    </asp:comparevalidator>
```

In the code behind, we set the ValueToCompare property like so:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then

    cmvDate.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Now.ToString("d")   

End If
```

Intermittently (we can't discern a pattern), we get the following error:

"The value '' of the ValueToCompare property of 'cmvDate' cannot be converted to type 'Date'."

With a call stack of:

```
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator.ControlPropertiesValid() 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.get_PropertiesValid() 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.Validate() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.Validate() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.Validate(String validationGroup) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
```

My first thought was something odd with the date format, but we're using UK dates, last error was on 18th July, so the ValueToCompare gets set to 18/07/2011.  I've set this manually using the debugger, and it worked fine.  Anybody any bright ideas as to why this may be happening?

1. I've checked the code - there is nowhere else that this is being set.
2. Using the debugger, I've double checked at postback, and as expected, this property value is retained.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Did get the text then the error occurs?

Comment: @VMAtm - Our culture is en-UK, and no, we don't have the text.

Comment: Well, is `viewstate` is on? May be, during post back comparer just can't create the date to compare?

Comment: The fact it sometimes works could be related also to the type of client (for example if the browser is a low level browser, like a portable device one). CompareControls is capable of using different code (you can check that using Reflector - method EvaluateIsValid)

Comment: @Simon Mourier - that's entirely possible.  I didn't think we really had too many people browsing on a mobile (due to the nature of the site), but it may be worth looking into. (although, looking at the error report, it seems to be IE7 as the browser agent).

Answer (score 5):

> The value '' of the ValueToCompare property of 'cmvDate' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.

This error message says, that in moment of validation property `ValueToCompare` of your rangeValidator itself (not the control you are validating) is not set. This can be if you wrote this lines:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    cmvDate.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Now.ToString("d")   
End If
```

not in `Page_Init` event.

1. Move the code of setting the `ValueToCompare` to the [Init event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), with removing the check for Postback.
2. Check, what value has this property during data check (may be, you should remove check for `Not IsPostBack`).
3. Set this property before check is occured.

Comment: None of these explain why this all works most of the time, and only intermittently fails.

Comment: You didn't tell your code is working for sometimes. You didn't tell about debug information - what `valueToCompare` has your validator. I've explained, when your code *can* fail - in moment of validation, if you didn't set the `valueToCompare`.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but beg to differ, this is all in the original question.

Comment: +1 @VMAtm - At the moment of validation there is no `ValueToCompare`. And you are only setting it within an `If` on `Page_Load`. This can explain why sometimes it doesn't work. For some reason during a postback the `valueToCompare` was not there and never got re-set. If you move it to `Init` not within an if condition, does that work?

Comment: @bgs264 If you remove the if condition, yes, it will work - initialization velues are overriden after, but in this case there is no lines they will be overriden.

Comment: @Paddy Did you remove the check for the `IsPostBack`?

Comment: @VMAtm - I haven't done, and this may well rectify the problem described, but I'm still curious as to why it's happening at all.

Comment: @Paddy Well, if you will remove this check, and after that everything will work, then this control doesn't save its state in `ViewState`. This can be if you are initialize the property not in `Page_Load`, but in `Page_Init`. Why are you not checking all possibilities? You must locate the error, not just sit and wait for something.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I appreciate that this may fix the symptoms of the problem, but given that it only happens intermittently, it tells me that I shouldn't have to do this.  I much prefer to get to the root of the problem (which may have unknown effects elsewhere) as opposed to fixing the symptoms and putting a plaster over it.

Comment: @Paddy If you know that this problem is because of wrong `ViewState` behaviour, you can solve it. I don't suggest you to completely remove the check - just try it out, is the problem there, or not.

Answer (score 2):

In your control settings you set `type="Date"` whitch means that you will compare value as a `DateTime` object, but in the `ValueToCompare` property you set `string` object, not a `DateTime`.

If you need to compare by strings - set control setting `type` to `String`,
If you need to compare by dates - set `DateTime` object to the `ValueToCompare` control property and `Operator="DataTypeCheck"`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any other ViewState-related errors? Like "*Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that `<machineKey>` configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.*"?

If so, maybe the problem is related to one of the things listed in this [MS KB article: Intermittent Invalid Viewstate Error in ASP.NET Web pages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555353).

> There are several conditions that may cause this issue. Each known condition is presented with a short explanation and a possible workaround.
>   Application Pool Recycling
>   Server Farms or Server Clusters
>   Form Posts
>   Proxy servers and Virus Scanners

One other possible thing not mentioned in that article is a slow or unreliable connection along with resulting impatience of users. I worked on an app hosted in the US but many users are from India. We noticed a much greater frequency of these types of intermittent ViewState-related errors among the users in India. We speculated that it might have been because of higher latency, greater number of hops, lower bandwidth and users interacting with pages prior to page load completion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - we do work in a web farm, but we are already set up to match the machine keys across the sites, and we don't get these viewstate type errors any more.  It's entirely possible that this is somehow related, but the strange thing is that there is only one page in the application where this is currently happening.