# Comparevalidator on date type c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, comparevalidator

how to solve this problem? 
I am having the same problem related to this link which was not answered. 
Can anyone help me.

```
 <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="DateTextBox" runat="server" Culture="en-GB" MinDate="1901-01-01"
                                TabIndex="4" FocusedDate="1991-01-01" MaxDate="2099-01-01">
                                <Calendar UseColumnHeadersAsSelectors="False" UseRowHeadersAsSelectors="False" ViewSelectorText="x">
                                </Calendar>
                                <DateInput DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" DisplayDateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" TabIndex="4">
                                </DateInput>                                                                  
                            </telerik:RadDatePicker>

  <asp:CompareValidator ID="dateCompareValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DateTextBox" ToolTip="The date to achieve the objective must be in the future"
                                    ErrorMessage="The date to achieve the objective must be in the future" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Date"
                                    ValueToCompare='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>'>*</asp:CompareValidator>
```

[Intermittent error with CompareValidator - ValueToCompare property is ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746115/intermittent-error-with-comparevalidator-valuetocompare-property-is)

Comment: You have to post your problem in the opening post. You may edit your post.

Comment: Answered in linked question. The main idea is that you wants to compare strings but you set data type `Date`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set following properties of `CompareValidator` to validate date input.

1. ControlToValidate="controlId"
2. ErrorMessage="Error Message description"
3. Type="Date"
4. Operator="DataTypeCheck"

EDIT: Realized after the update of OP.

May be you have to set `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

```
 ValueToCompare='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>'>
```

Take a look at threads at telerik forum:

1. http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/calendar/raddatepicker-validate-manually-entered-value.aspx
2. http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/calendar/validation-of-non-mandatory-datepicker-control.aspx
3. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/validation/defaultcs.aspx